# cannot found lodash in npm installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, testem

I installed lodash and several other libraries this way:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-testem --save-dev
npm install sinon --save-dev
npm install -g phantomjs
npm install lodash --save
npm install jquery --save
```

When I run testem using grunt (or directly), I found the following problem

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Digging into the issue, I found the issue in the mode following line

```
module.exports = require('./lodash');
```

(I have to point that the ./ is added by the installer. I even tried to remove it, but the error persist)

This is located on index.js, inside the node_modules/lodash folder
I think this is an issue of installation, but no matter what I do, it continue failing. I update npm, I remove node_modules and install all over again, but this continue happens.

Any advice or clue will be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the relative path of modules that are inside the node_modules directory, just passing the module name will do the trick:

```
require('lodash');
```

Now node.js will automatically look inside the node_modules directory for you, simple as that <3.

Comment: Marcelo Alves, I didn't added the ./ to the lodash path. That's how npm install him. And I tried to change that, but the result it's the same